# PHP MySql nested subqueries in codeigniter. Database not found?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = "' . strtolower($first_name) . '" AND last_name = "' . strtolower($last_name) . '" ORDER BY user_level ASC) AS users GROUP BY users.email');
```

...which works perfectly in my SQL client. I cannot get my head around how to convert it to active record and I shouldn't technically need to I don't think. Anyway. I'm getting a 'Database not selected' error and I don't know why. If I print out the `$this->db` object it's all there, database info and all so I'm not sure how to make this work? This is the error shown:

```
Error Number: 1046

No database selected

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = "andy" AND last_name = "hall" ORDER BY user_level ASC) AS users GROUP BY users.email
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't see the woods through the trees and I'm on a tight schedule so any help is seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First check you have a line `$active_group = 'default';` at the beginning of the database.php file.

I'd suggest setting `$db['default']['pconnect']` to `false` instead of `true`. Lots of people have had connection problems using that.